# Change event of jquery is not functioning properly

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 $('#date').bind("change",function(){
  var x=$("#date").val();
  alert(x);
 });
});
```

Corresponding html code:

```
 <form id="form1">
  <tr>
    <td class="tr_tab"><a class="qtn_data">I am:</td><td class="tr_tab"> </a> 
      <input type="radio value="male" name="gender" /><a class="qtn_data">Male</a>&nbsp
      <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender"/>
      <a class="qtn_data">Female</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <hr/ id="hr3">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="tr_tab"><a class="qtn_data">Date of birth:</td><td class="tr_tab"> </a> 
      <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Date" MaxLength="2" id="date" />&nbsp
      <input type="text" placeholder="Month" MaxLength="2" id="month" />&nbsp
      <input type="text" placeholder="Year" id="year" MaxLength="4" />&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><span style="float:left;"><a class="qtn_data1">ex: 02/05/1992</a></span>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <hr/ id="hr3">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="qtn_data">I am from:</a>

    </td>
    <td>
  <input type="text" id="place" placeholder="Town" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="place" placeholder="State" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="place" placeholder="Country" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

Alert is showing in `Opera` and `Firefox` when I move to another window after changing text in textbox with `id="date"` but there is no effect in `Chrome`..

Comment: Hm, works in Chrome for me (albeit with a couple of errors in the console): http://jsfiddle.net/L9rwN/

Comment: `id="place"` multiple instances.

Comment: may be this `<hr/ id="hr3">` change to this `<hr id="hr3" />`

Comment: He is not trying with `place`, he is trying with id `date`

Comment: @sahal then his code is working in chrome, i just tested.

Comment: what is "when I move to another window after changing text"   ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is incrrect HTML

change

```
  <tr>
     <td class="tr_tab"><a class="qtn_data">Date of birth:</td><td class="tr_tab"> </a> 
      <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Date" MaxLength="2" id="date" />&nbsp
      <input type="text" placeholder="Month" MaxLength="2" id="month" />&nbsp
      <input type="text" placeholder="Year" id="year" MaxLength="4" />&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
```

to

```
  <tr>
     <td class="tr_tab"><a class="qtn_data">Date of birth: </a> </td>
     <td class="tr_tab">
      <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Date" MaxLength="2" id="date" />&nbsp
      <input type="text" placeholder="Month" MaxLength="2" id="month" />&nbsp
      <input type="text" placeholder="Year" id="year" MaxLength="4" />&nbsp
     </td>
  </tr>
```

here you have closed the `</td>` before close the `</a>`

```
<td class="tr_tab"><a class="qtn_data">Date of birth:</td><td class="tr_tab"> </a>
```

also there are `HTML` errors in other places , check and correct them

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Learn more about binding `change` event here...

http://api.jquery.com/change/

EX:-

```
$(document).ready( function()
    $('#date').click(function() {
      $('#date').change();
    });

    $('#date').change(function() {
       var x=$("#date").val();
       alert(x);
    });
});
```

Comment: You cannot invoke the change event like that.  Furthermore, Chrome and Opera both support it: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html.